# How to test the state of multiple toggle buttons in cypress

Tags: cypress, toggle

I have mutiple toggles which has initial value
`<div class="test-switch-slider"`
However on toggling on the value changes to
`<div class="test-switch-slider slideron"`

How do I test multiple sliders with value sliderone

Comment: you can use the .each() function to iterate over all the elements that match a certain selector.

Answer (score 2):

The exact way to test depends on what happens when you carry out the toggle.

Try using the `{multiple:true}` option to toggle all switches at once.

```js
cy.get('div.test-switch-slider')
  .should('not.have.class', 'slideron')   // initial state - no slideron class

cy.get('div.test-switch-slider')
  .click({multiple:true})                 // toggle all switches

cy.get('div.test-switch-slider')
  .each($el => {
    cy.wrap($el).should('have.class', 'slideron')     // each toggle has slideron
  })
```

You can also try with `.each()` to toggle individually, but if there is a change to the DOM during the loop this might not work.

```js
cy.get('div.test-switch-slider')
  .should('not.have.class', 'slideron')   // initial state - no slideron class

cy.get('div.test-switch-slider')
  .each(($el, index) => {
    cy.log(`Switch ${index}`)            // log which switch 
    cy.wrap($el).click()                 // toggle the switch
    cy.wrap($el).should('have.class', 'slideron')
  })
```